# Compiling a software with GTK which has no configuration script

Tags: compiling, gtk-2

I bumped into [green](https://github.com/schandinat/green), a PDF viewer for the Framebuffer. I would like to compile it, but I am not having much success, although I have installed all the dependencies...

The error I am getting is:

```
$/home/Data/Software/green-0.2$ make
cc -D GREEN_SYSCONFIG_FILE=\"/usr/local/etc/green.conf\" -D GREEN_USERCONFIG_FILE=\".green.conf\" -Os -Wall -c main.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) -o main.o
cc -Os -Wall -c green.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) -o green.o
cc -Os -Wall -c sdl.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) $(sdl-config --cflags) -o sdl.o
sdl.c: In function ‘GetInput’:
sdl.c:91:3: warning: case value ‘37’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:85:3: warning: case value ‘123’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:86:3: warning: case value ‘125’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:94:3: warning: case value ‘126’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:90:3: warning: case value ‘4294967207’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c: In function ‘RenderPage’:
sdl.c:120:2: error: unknown type name ‘GdkPixbuf’
sdl.c:120:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_new’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:120:34: error: ‘GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
sdl.c:120:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sdl.c:136:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_page_render_to_pixbuf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:137:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:137:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
sdl.c:138:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c:139:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c: In function ‘Green_SDL_Main’:
sdl.c:402:21: warning: variable ‘left_y’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
sdl.c:402:9: warning: variable ‘left_x’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
make: *** [sdl.o] Error 1
$:/home/Data/Software/green-0.2$
```

Obviously he can't find GdkPixbuf, but this construct is defined in:

```
# ls /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h 
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h
```

When I add to the file sdl.c the following line:

```
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
```

I am "greeted" with following error:

```
# make
cc -Os -Wall -c sdl.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) $(sdl-config --cflags) -o sdl.o
sdl.c:20:35: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sdl.o] Error 1
```

My question is then, how do I "convince" gcc to compile this code?

Thanks in advance, 
Oz

UPDATE:

with:

```
#include "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-core.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-features.h"
#include "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-enum-types.h"
```

added to sdl.c

I am getting the following errors:

```
:/home/Data/Software/green-0.2$ make
cc -D GREEN_SYSCONFIG_FILE=\"/usr/local/etc/green.conf\" -D GREEN_USERCONFIG_FILE=\".green.conf\" -Os -Wall -c main.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags)  $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags) -o main.o
cc -Os -Wall -c green.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags)  $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags) -o green.o
cc -Os -Wall -c sdl.c $(pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags) $(sdl-config --cflags) $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags) -o sdl.o
sdl.c: In function ‘GetInput’:
sdl.c:101:3: warning: case value ‘37’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:95:3: warning: case value ‘123’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:96:3: warning: case value ‘125’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:104:3: warning: case value ‘126’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c:100:3: warning: case value ‘4294967207’ not in enumerated type ‘SDLKey’ [-Wswitch]
sdl.c: In function ‘RenderPage’:
sdl.c:146:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘poppler_page_render_to_pixbuf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
sdl.c: In function ‘Green_SDL_Main’:
sdl.c:412:21: warning: variable ‘left_y’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
sdl.c:412:9: warning: variable ‘left_x’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
cc main.o green.o sdl.o $(pkg-config poppler-glib --libs) $(sdl-config --libs)  $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags) -o green
sdl.o: In function `RenderPage':
sdl.c:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `gdk_pixbuf_new'
sdl.c:(.text+0x283): undefined reference to `poppler_page_render_to_pixbuf'
sdl.c:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels'
sdl.c:(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride'
sdl.c:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [green] Error 1
```

My guess is that there is some gcc flag I am missing? or linking?

Comment: Is libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev installed? `dpkg -l | grep libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`. The `-dev` packages contain header files required to compile software that wants to use it.

Comment: @jippie, yes, it is intalled. I already wrote, all the dependencies are installed. But the sources come with a very minimal make file, without configuration script.

Comment: How about `#include "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h"`

Comment: @jippie, well, it get's me forwared beyond the error, but i get new ones. Posted them up there...

Comment: I think it is a *search path* setting, but I'm unfamiliar with how to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an answer, not really fully compiling, but I managed to solve the part where sdl.c fails to compile with:

```
cc -c sdl.c `sdl-config --cflags` `pkg-config poppler-glib --cflags` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` -o sdl.o
```